# Dragging event not working on React leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, marker

I'm trying to update the latitude and longitude coordinates after dragging a Marker over an Leaflet map in my React project. This is my map container component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import './styles/Map.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
//import {MarkerIcon} from './Icon.js';
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import iconShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon,
    shadowUrl: iconShadow
});

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;

class Mapa extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentLocation: { lat: -16.399, lng: -71.536 },
            zoom: 17,
        }
        this.updatePosition = this.updatePosition.bind(this);
    }

    updatePosition = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hola");
        /*this.setState({currentLocation:e.latlng})*/
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <MapContainer center={this.state.currentLocation} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
                <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" attribution="© <a href='https://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors" />
                <Marker position={this.state.currentLocation} draggable={true} onDragend={this.updatePosition}>
                    <Popup>{"Latitud: "+this.state.currentLocation.lat}<br /> {"Longitud: "+this.state.currentLocation.lng}</Popup>
                </Marker>
            </MapContainer>
        );
    }

}

export default Mapa;
```

However nothing happened after dragging the Marker, i've tried to change the name of the event, but none is shown on console. Everything else is working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `onDragend` method available on Marker in version 3. You need to use a functional component to make it work using `eventHandlers`

Comment: You're right! I made a function wrapper for my class and now everything is working! Thanks @kboul !!